# How can I alter the php get_included_files array?

Tags: php, .htaccess

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php

get_included_files — Returns an array with the names of included or required files

I need to be able to alter that array to stop inclusion of certain files.  I know this is a terrible design flaw, but I am presented with a problem of updating some read only files as a temporary solution while we complete a more permanent solution.  I was able to make a second set of the files and use .htaccess to redirect the web requests to my hacked files, but I would like to use the original files where modifications were not needed.

Long story short, if I can add a file to the array of files that have already been included my problem will be solved.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to tell PHP to pretend that it's included certain files, when it really hasn't?

Comment: If there is any solution to your problem, it is not "altering the included files" . So let's look at your goal: preventing the inclusion of files. Your possibilities depend on a) which files you can technically modify (talking about write permissions, not about what should not be modified) and b) how the files are included (include, include_once, require, require_once). Please add this information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

By removing content from the array that **get_included_files()** function will return, will not help you. you need to manually remove that require or include line from the particular file where it is being used. If you are using any debugging tool it would be very helpful. Even eclipse 'll be helpful